# In an array how to know if selected indexes can create a rectangle or a square?

Tags: algorithm

I have an array like this:

```
array = [
0, 1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6, 7,
8, 9, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14, 15
];
```

And an input like following:

```
input = [5,6,9,10]
```

When we compare this input with the array we can see that this input actually creates a square on the array.

```
input = [6,9,10]
```

This one, on the contary, creates a triangle.

I want to write a function that checks if the input given creates a **rectangle or square**. If so returns true, else returns false. How can I write that function?

Comment: Can you explain what is the condition such that 4 points form a rectangle respectively 3 points form a triangle? Does it have to do with the way you are wrapping lines in `array`? Why is 1 missing in `array`?

Comment: Would you call [2,5,7,10] a square or rectangle?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz only condition is that we should select 4 points in ascending order, I'm sorry I added 1 in the array.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski It's such a good question, answer is no.

Comment: Ok, kind of referring to the comments under @LSerni answer - since you don't know either width, or height, what makes you think the field 4x4, why not 2x8, or 8x2 should it always be a square?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski So I wasn't really sure about the size and that was just an assumption, now I know that we can know the size. Just sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish beforehand whether the source array is a square or a rectangle.

The internal representation is identical even if the array is not a square with W = 4 and H = 4 but

```
[ 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ];
```

which is a rectangle with W = 8, H = 2.

You can see that (5,6,9,10) makes a square if W=4, but makes nothing if W=8.

**Supposing that you know the array's width W** (and therefore its height H, which is the size of the array divided by W), then if you have an element N, such as 5, its bidimensional coordinates in the WH system are

```
{ 
  x: N % W, 
  y: floor(N / W)
}
```

So you see that N=5 becomes (1,1). Once you have the bidimensional coordinates of all the elements, checking the shape is straightforward.

Square and rectangle: you have four elements, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4). It is a square or a rectangle, oriented like the array, if x1=x3, y1=y2, x2=x4 and y3=y4. If, then, x2-x1 is equal to y3-y1, it is a square; otherwise a rectangle.

You can add more complicated conditions to check for other arrangements. For example, the 1-2 side is the square root of (x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1). The same can be done with the 1-3 and 2-4 diagonals and all the other sides. If the diagonals are of equal length, it is a rectangle (or a square). If, additionally, the 1-2 and 2-3 sides are equal, then it is a square. This more complicated condition works whatever the orientation of the square (i.e., (2,6,8,10) would be recognized as a square).

Three points are always a triangle unless the sum of two of the three sides is exactly equal to the third (this is a *degenerate triangle*). If the square of the length of one side is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two, you get a rectangular triangle. Checking for isosceles and equilateral is straightforward.

If you do not know W, then you need to factorise the size S of the array and try all possibilities. 16 is 2*2*2*2, so you need to check W=2, W=4, W=8 and W=16.

Comment: Hey, since it is an one dimensional array I really don't know the height and the width of the rectangle or square.

Comment: Okay, added that case.

Comment: One more thing, if we know coordinates like you write (1,1), (1,2)... How can we assure it is actually an square or rectangle?

Comment: @MehmetAliKarakamış you can apply any one of several geometrical tests. I have added the first that came to my mind, but verify them since I might have made some mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rectangle has to be axis-aligned, and the input is ordered, then `[a, b, c, d]` forms a rectangle if `(4096*a + 256*b + 16*d + c) % 17 = 0`.

This only works for this particular arrangement of the values from 0 to 15. If you have 25 values (0-24) arranged similarly, you can use `(15625*a + 625*b + 25*d + c) % 26 = 0` instead. The pattern is generalizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a given input is a rectangle or a triangle by defining two methods `isRectangle` and `isTriangle` and call

```
return isTriangle(input) OR is Rectangle(input)
```

with

```
isRectangle(input):
   return length(input) == 4 AND input[0] < input [1] < input[2] < input [3]
```

and

```
isTriangle(input):
   return length(input) == 3 AND input[0] < input [1] < input[2]
```